# Breaking the law in another country?

Tags: international

What happens if you go to another country break the law there, but it's not illegal in the country you live in?
Example:
Person A goes to vacation to country 2. Person A is from country 1, where you can use sneakers whenever you want.
In country 2 one is allowed to use sneakers on Saturdays 8am-3pm.
Then person A uses sneakers in country 2 on a sunday and gets caught. The punishment of using sneakers outside the law timelimit would be 90 days. What would happen?

Answer (score 5):

When you are in another country, you are subject to their laws - you may be arrested and go through the due process as defined by that countries laws.

This potentially means anything from a fine, to incarceration or deportation or even execution, depending on the local countries laws.

A good example is the caning of American citizen [Michael Fay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_P._Fay) in 1994 by the Singapore authorities, as a judicial punishment for vandalism, or the case of Swiss citizen [Oliver Fricker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oliver_Fricker), who was also caned in 2010 for vandalism.